# Aurelia CLI Karma Configuration

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, aurelia

How can I configure an Aurelia project using the CLI to load tests from within the src folder? Attempting to adjust the unitTestTunner section int eh aurelia.json results in the test task not being able to find the setup.js file.